# Get indices of numpy 1d array where value is greater than previous element

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

Say I generate a 1d numpy array:

```
r=np.random.randint(0,10,(10,))
```

giving, for example:

```
array([1, 5, 6, 7, 7, 8, 8, 0, 2, 7])
```

I can find the indices where the element is greater than the previous(the element to the left) like this:

```
for x in range(r.shape[0]):
    if r[x]>r[x-1]:
        p[x]=1
    else:
        p[x]=0
np.where(p==1)[0]
```

giving:

```
array([1, 2, 3, 5, 8, 9])
```

Is there a better way of doing this?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can use [`numpy.diff`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.diff.html) with [`numpy.where`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.where.html):

```
>>> arr = np.array([1, 5, 6, 7, 7, 8, 8, 0, 2, 7])
>>> np.where(np.diff(arr) > 0)[0] + 1
array([1, 2, 3, 5, 8, 9])
```

Comment: I'd put a comment on why the +1. Might not be obvious at first sight (or second 6 months later)

Answer (score 0):

An alternative would be to use array slicing:

```
>>> arr = np.array([1, 5, 6, 7, 7, 8, 8, 0, 2, 7])
>>> np.where(np.r_[False, arr[1:] > arr[:-1]])[0]
array([1, 2, 3, 5, 8, 9])
```

You shift the array one to the right and compare it with itself. The length of the result is shorter than the original array. Since the first value can not be compared with one to it's left you set the first result to false.